# Making a list of elements from particular parameters in a JSON file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing an assignment for school and I am asked to make a list of names of nobel peace prize winners for a particular year and category. 
This is a sample of the JSON file:

```
[{
        'year': '2018',
        'category': 'physics',
        'overallMotivation': '“for       groundbreaking inventions in the field of laser physics”',
        'laureates': [{
                'id': '960',
                'firstname': 'Arthur',
                'surname': 'Ashkin',
                'motivation': '"for the optical tweezers and their application to biological systems"',
                'share': '2'
            }, {
                'id': '961',
                'firstname': 'Gérard',
                'surname': 'Mourou',
                'motivation': '"for their method of generating high-intensity, ultra-short optical pulses"',
                'share': '4'
            }, {
                'id': '962',
                'firstname': 'Donna',
                'surname': 'Strickland',
                'motivation': '"for their method of generating high-intensity, ultra-short optical pulses"',
                'share': '4'
            }
        ]
    }, {
        'year': '2018',
        'category': 'chemistry',
        'laureates': [{
                'id': '963',
                'firstname': 'Frances H.',
                'surname': 'Arnold',
                'motivation': '"for the directed evolution of enzymes"',
                'share': '2'
            }, {
                'id': '964',
                'firstname': 'George P.',
                'surname': 'Smith',
                'motivation': '"for the phage display of peptides and antibodies"',
                'share': '4'
            }, {
                'id': '965',
                'firstname': 'Sir Gregory P.',
                'surname': 'Winter',
                'motivation': '"for the phage display of peptides and antibodies"',
                'share': '4'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I am supposed to find a way to find the full names of the people who won for a particular category and year, this is my current code

```
def get_laureates(dict_prizes, year = "none", category = "none"):


    names = []
    for row in dict_prizes: 
        if row["category"] == category:
            names.append(row["firstname"] + row['surname'])
    return names

year = 2018
category = "peace"

get_laureates(dict_prizes, year = 2018, category = "peace")
```

and this is the output

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-168-57a2293c1bca> in <module>
         11 category = "peace"
         12 # test your function here
    ---> 13 get_laureates(dict_prizes, category = "peace")

    <ipython-input-168-57a2293c1bca> in get_laureates(dict_prizes, year,         category)
          4     names = []
          5     for row in dict_prizes:
    ----> 6         if row["category"] == category and row["year"] == year:
          7             names.append(row["firstname"] + row['surname'])
          8     return names

    TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I know there are many errors in this code, I've been unable to convert year into integers, even with the removal of the "years" parameter, I am unable to generate a result with just the category. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am totally clueless when it comes to JSON (The reading material given to me literally just taught me about dump and load).

Comment: Are you sure that your input data matches that as far as the outer part is concerned? The error is that `dict_prizes` is returning a list, you are iterating that list and returning a string for `row` which is why `row["category"]` is causing that error.

Comment: Why does the json start with a `[` bracket and end with a `}` curly braces? What is the correct format? I can help you work out the function, but need the correct format to begin with.

Comment: @CeliusStingher it isn't the end of the entire json, that was just part of it! The json itself does end with a ]

Comment: Gotcha. Working on it

Comment: I doubt introducing new packages is a good idea if it's homework.

Answer (score 0):

Your code generally works which means there is something you are missing on your input data that you didn't post here. I could not reproduce the exact error you are seeing with the data you gave us.

There is one issue that you aren't considering -- you need to loop through the `laureates` as well and then pull out that winner since that is also a list of dictionaries. I did that below:

```py
dict_prizes = [{'year': '2018', 'category': 'physics', 'overallMotivation': '“for       groundbreaking inventions in the field of laser physics”', 'laureates': [{'id': '960', 'firstname': 'Arthur', 'surname': 'Ashkin', 'motivation': '"for the optical tweezers and their application to biological systems"', 'share': '2'}, {'id': '961', 'firstname': 'Gérard', 'surname': 'Mourou', 'motivation': '"for their method of generating high-intensity, ultra-short optical pulses"', 'share': '4'}, {'id': '962', 'firstname': 'Donna', 'surname': 'Strickland', 'motivation': '"for their method of generating high-intensity, ultra-short optical pulses"', 'share': '4'}]}, {'year': '2018', 'category': 'chemistry', 'laureates': [{'id': '963', 'firstname': 'Frances H.', 'surname': 'Arnold', 'motivation': '"for the directed evolution of enzymes"', 'share': '2'}, {'id': '964', 'firstname': 'George P.', 'surname': 'Smith', 'motivation': '"for the phage display of peptides and antibodies"', 'share': '4'}, {'id': '965', 'firstname': 'Sir Gregory P.', 'surname': 'Winter', 'motivation': '"for the phage display of peptides and antibodies"', 'share': '4'}]}]

def get_laureates(dict_prizes, year = "none", category = "none"):
    names = []
    for row in dict_prizes: 
        if row["category"] == category:
            for winner in row['laureates']:   # You need this loop for the inner list of dictionaries
                names.append(winner['firstname'] + winner['surname'])
    return names

year = 2018
category = "physics"

get_laureates(dict_prizes=dict_prizes, year=2018, category=category)
```

And got:

```
>>> get_laureates(dict_prizes=dict_prizes, year=2018, category=category)
['ArthurAshkin', 'GérardMourou', 'DonnaStrickland']
```

Since you are taking in `year` you'll need to solve for that part as well which I didn't include since you didn't.

Answer (score 0):

For the provided data you have a list of JSON objects, each of which comprises of

```
'year': type (string)
'category': type(string)
'overallMotivation': type(string)
'laureates' : type(list) - > this list comprises of more json objects
```

Since you need the first and the last name of all the author, you need to traverse through both the list. The initial one first to match the "year" and "category" (to match your year kindly change the data-type of year to string), then traverse through the "laureates" and keep on appending `row["firstname"] + row['surname']`

```
def get_laureates(dict_prizes, year = None, category = None):
    names = []
    for category_wise_elements in dict_prizes:
        if category_wise_elements["category"] == category and 
           category_wise_elements['year'] == str(year):
            for winner in category_wise_elements['laureates']:
                names.append(winner["firstname"] + winner['surname'])
    return names

year = 2018
category = "peace"

get_laureates(dict_prizes, year = 2018, category = "peace")
```

I hope this should help you

Answer (score 0):

Here, I just solved your function by using and if that checks that both `year` and `category` match the input you are giving them. That way you can search for all values belonging to that specific criteria. Furthermore, **`year` needs to be treated as string** when checking for condition because of how it is expressed within the json file. You can obviously delete the `else:` line which was made only for validation purposes.

```
def get_laureates(category,year,json):  
    names = []
    for j in range(len(json)):
        if (json[j]['year'] == str(year)) and (json[j]['category'] == category):
            for i in range(len(json[j]['laureates'])):
                names.append(json[j]['laureates'][i]['firstname'] + ' ' + json[j]['laureates'][i]['surname'])
        else:
            print('Not found for category '+category+' and year '+str(year))
    return names
print(get_laureates(category='physics',year=2018,json=json))
```

Output:

```
Not found for category physics and year 2018
['Arthur Ashkin', 'Gérard Mourou', 'Donna Strickland']
```

### Super check for consistency

You can add this right after defining the function:

```
possibilities = ['physics','chemistry']
for i in range(len(possibilities)):
    print(get_laureates(category=possibilities[i],year=2018,json=json))
```

Output:

```
Not found for category physics and year 2018
['Arthur Ashkin', 'Gérard Mourou', 'Donna Strickland']
Not found for category chemistry and year 2018
['Frances H. Arnold', 'George P. Smith', 'Sir Gregory P. Winter']
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pythonic Solution:

- Using [`nested list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions)
- Using the [membership operator, `in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations)
- `f'{} {}'` is an [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python)
- The function is implemented using [PEP 484 -- Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)
- The caveat being, `data` is in the form of the `list` of `dicts` supplied in the question

```py
def get_name(cat: str, year: str, data: list) -> list:
    return [f"{n['firstname']} {n['surname']}" for d in data for n in d['laureates'] if d['category'] == cat and d['year'] == year]

print(get_name('physics', '2018', data))

>>> ['Arthur Ashkin', 'Gérard Mourou', 'Donna Strickland']
```

### Pandas Solution:

- [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/)
- [`pandas.io.json.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) to get the data into the dataframe.
- [Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

# create the dataframe
df = json_normalize(data, 'laureates', ['year', 'category'])

# create a column named 'Full Name'
df['Full Name'] = df.firstname.str.cat(df.surname, sep=' ')

print(df)

  id       firstname     surname                                                                   motivation share  year   category              Full Name
 960          Arthur      Ashkin       "for the optical tweezers and their application to biological systems"     2  2018    physics          Arthur Ashkin
 961          Gérard      Mourou  "for their method of generating high-intensity, ultra-short optical pulses"     4  2018    physics          Gérard Mourou
 962           Donna  Strickland  "for their method of generating high-intensity, ultra-short optical pulses"     4  2018    physics       Donna Strickland
 963      Frances H.      Arnold                                      "for the directed evolution of enzymes"     2  2018  chemistry      Frances H. Arnold
 964       George P.       Smith                           "for the phage display of peptides and antibodies"     4  2018  chemistry        George P. Smith
 965  Sir Gregory P.      Winter                           "for the phage display of peptides and antibodies"     4  2018  chemistry  Sir Gregory P. Winter

# search for your criteria
df['Full Name'][(df.category == 'physics') & (df.year == '2018')].tolist()

>>> ['Arthur Ashkin', 'Gérard Mourou', 'Donna Strickland']
```

Answer (score 0):

A didactic foolproof solution:

```
def extract_names(list_names):
    # Extraction of fisrtname and surname in "laureates"
    return [
        "{} {}".format(dicc.get('firstname', ''), dicc.get('surname', '')) for dicc in list_names
    ]


def get_nobels(list_data, year='', category=''):
    # We create the condition of identification of year and category:
    bool_condition = lambda _: _.get('year') == str(year) and _.get('category') == str(category)

    # Extraction of the names that meet the condition:
    elements_select = [
        extract_names(dicc.get('laureates', [])) for dicc in list_data if bool_condition(dicc)
    ][0]

    return elements_select


print(get_nobels(list_nobel, 2018, 'chemistry'))
```